# How do I read the definition part of google?

Tags: c#, html

This is a pretty specific question.

What I want to do is read this part of google search, if it exists:

[image]

I want to basically read that exact part and spit it back at the user. I have most of the rest of the program done, I just need this last part. I can't even find the element ID, which is why I'm asking here. The code I would use to get it would be:

```
var text = browser.Document.GetElementById("ID HERE");
//Browser is the name of my WebBrowser control
MessageBox.Show("The result was: " + text, "MyProgramName", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Also, am I Doing this efficiently? Is there a better way of doing this? I'm not using any type of multithreading here.

Comment: There might be an API provided by Google for this, but other than being unreliable, forgetting efficiency, this - screen-scraping - [is against Google's T&Cs](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/).

Answer (score 2):

There is no ID for that element.

[image]

Probably to make it harder for people to do this sort of thing.

### Update

If you are still looking at how to do this (are you trying to just get the definition of a word?) then perhaps you can use Wiktionary. They have an API you can use which is very well-documented here: http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php and here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: You'd think they would not assign a ID to the search bar or the search button to make it hard. Is there another way to get this text?

Comment: Try doing something like first td after table w/ class cs, if you can't find that class anywhere else in the code.